# Can "they" be used without an explicit antecedent noun phrase in a sentence like this?

Tags: sentence, pronouns, antecedents, anaphora

Can I say "His wife is named Jane, **and they have two sons**," or do I have to say "**he has** two sons" instead of "**they have**"? My paragraph was about the man, so is it wrong to say "they have" instead of "he has"?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to convey.

Comment: It's fine as it stands.  I would probably say 'called' rather than 'named'.  I might even say simply that "His wife *is* Jane..." (always assuming that the two sons are theirs and not his only from a relationship !)

Comment: My paragraph was about the man, so is it wrong to  say they have instead of he has? @Lawrence

Comment: The gender-neutral singular *they* isn't the natural reading of *they* in that context, so you should use *he* to refer to just the man.

Comment: As you wrote it, "they" includes Jane.  If you say "he" instead of "they," it becomes uncertain whether Jane is the mother of the two boys, or perhaps only the mother of one of them . . .

Comment: I understand "they" here to mean the couple, he and Jane.  Perhaps he (or she) has other sons as well, but together they have two sons.